# AllocatorAwareContainer and copy-and-swap idiom

Tags: c++, c++11, idioms

I'm trying to learn data structures along with idiomatic C++ and because of stuff like this I feel like it's probably not the best way to learn either. Let's say I wanted to implement a dynamic array class which would meet the *Container*, *ReversibleContainer* and *AllocatorAwareContainer* named requirements.

The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) page on *AllocatorAwareContainer* says:

> The only way to replace an allocator is copy-assignment,
>   move-assignment, and swap:
>
> 1. Copy-assignment will replace the allocator only if `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value`
>      is `true`
> 2. Move-assignment will replace the allocator only if `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value`
>      is `true`
> 3. Swap will replace the allocator only if `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`
>      is `true`. Specifically, it will exchange the allocator instances
>      through an unqualified call to the non-member function swap, see
>      Swappable.
>
> Note: swapping two containers with unequal allocators if
>   `propagate_on_container_swap` is `false` is undefined behavior.

What if I implement both of those assignment operators using copy-and-swap idiom? I mean, there aren't that many ways to check `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` and `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` if they are expressed in terms of move/copy constructor and a swap function. Is it safe to assume that when `propagate_on_container_swap` is true, the remaining two are true as well?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778199/is-there-something-similar-to-the-copy-and-swap-idiom-when-allocators-are-involv?rq=1, does that answer your questions?

Comment: @ecatmur After thinking about it, yes. I was more interested in seeing if I can get the copy-and-swap to work under those circumstances but if it's discouraged for good reasons then I guess there's no point in trying to use it.